# I would like to repeat the matrix in same order

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np
p = np.array([[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]])
t = np.array([[9],[6],[3]])
l = [2,3,4]
pt = np.multiply(p,t)
p = np.repeat(a = pt, repeats = l, axis=0)
print(p)
```

Whereas np.tile function repeats the same time for all rows, I want dynamic repeat instead.

[output for the above program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o607C.png)

But I would want the result to look like this
[[18,18,18],[12,12,12],[6,6,6],[18,18,18],[12,12,12],[6,6,6],[12,12,12],[6,6,6],[6,6,6]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom indexer:

```
m = max(l)

idx = np.tile(np.arange(len(pt)), m)
idx = idx[np.repeat(np.arange(m), len(l)) < np.tile(l, m)]

p = pt[idx]
```

Variant to compute the indexer with a 2D intermediate:

```
idx = np.tile(np.arange(m)[None], (len(l),1))
idx = idx[idx<np.array(l)[:,None]]
```

Output:

```
array([[18, 18, 18],
       [12, 12, 12],
       [ 6,  6,  6],
       [18, 18, 18],
       [12, 12, 12],
       [ 6,  6,  6],
       [12, 12, 12],
       [ 6,  6,  6],
       [ 6,  6,  6]])
```

Intermediate `idx`:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2])
```